# Add style details to a barplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have prepared the following plot:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y = [-0.015, 0.386, -0.273, -0.091, 0.955, 1.727]
errors = [0.744, 0.954, 0.737, 0.969, 0.848, 0.460]

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
plt.bar(x, y, yerr=errors, align='center', alpha=0.5, color='grey')
plt.xticks((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), ('', 'I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I4', 'I5', 'I6', ''))
plt.ylim((-3, 3))
plt.show()
```

I have a couple of questions:

- How do i add the bottom and top dashes in the error segment?
- I would like to color the background green if y > 0.8, yellow if -0.8 <= y <= 0.8, red if y < -0.8. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the horizontal lines, you need to use `capsize=n`. Larger the n, wider the horizontal lines. You can set the background color using `axvspan()` and select color based on the value of y. Below is the updated code. I changed y value of one to show the red color...

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y = [-0.015, 0.386, -0.273, -0.091, -0.955, 1.727]
errors = [0.744, 0.954, 0.737, 0.969, 0.848, 0.460]

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
ax=plt.bar(x, y, yerr=errors, align='center', alpha=0.5, color='grey', capsize=5)
plt.xticks((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), ('', 'I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I4', 'I5', 'I6', ''))
plt.ylim((-3, 3))
for i in range(1,7):
    if y[i-1]  > 0.8:
        color = 'green'
    elif y[i-1]  > -0.8:
        color = 'yellow'
    else:
        color = 'red'
    plt.axvspan(i-0.5, i+.5, facecolor=color, alpha=0.3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

As requested, you are looking for horizontal ranges. So, you would need to use `axhspan()`. To bring the gray to solid, change alpha to 1 and you will need to bring the bars to the front using `zorder()`. I also added `edgecolor='gray'` to keep the look of a fully solid bar. Code is below...

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
ax=plt.bar(x, y, yerr=errors, align='center', alpha=1, color='grey', edgecolor='gray',capsize=10, zorder=2)
plt.xticks((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), ('', 'I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I4', 'I5', 'I6', ''))
plt.ylim((-3, 3))

plt.axhspan(0.8, plt.gca().get_ylim()[1], facecolor='green', alpha=0.3, zorder=1)
plt.axhspan(-0.8, 0.8, facecolor='yellow', alpha=0.3, zorder=1)
plt.axhspan(plt.gca().get_ylim()[0], -0.8, facecolor='red', alpha=0.3, zorder=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The colored bands should be horizontal though. The top band should be green, the middle band yellow, and the bottom band red. I was referring to the y-values ​​of the vertical axis.

Comment: Pls check the EDIT section

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for. One last detail: is there a way to prevent the gray of the bars from overlapping other colors? That is, I would like a solid gray regardless of the background color.

Comment: Updated the EDIT section - use zorder and change alpha of bars to 1

Comment: Now `x = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]`. I want to print the y value centered over the top horizontal dash of the error. This is my code but it doesn't do exactly what is required (It is not centered). Could you tell me where the mistake is? `for i in x: plt.text(x=i, y=y[x.index(i)]+errors[x.index(i)]+0.2, s=f"{y[x.index(i)]}", fontdict=dict(fontsize=10))`

Comment: Try this... `for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.text(x[i]-.4, errors[i]+y[i]+0.05, round(y[i], 3) , fontdict=dict(fontsize=10))`. You might need to adjust the offsets a bit based on your figure size and number of x,y you have but should work